# Firebase-admin:- Deployment Failed: ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, firebase-admin

I'm using python-flask and firebase-admin (for authentication) in my mobile app backend. I'm deploying my code to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Everything is fine until I install the firebase-admin through "pip install firebase-admin".

I've committed changed to git.

Now, the deployment fails and displays the following message.

*MacBook-Pro:pets-friend-api santosh.guruju$ eb deploy

WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
WARNING: Git is in a detached head state. Using branch "default".
Creating application version archive "app-d517-170725_142037".
Uploading PetsFrenzAPI/app-d517-170725_142037.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-054100c8ffb51643c] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-054100c8ffb51643c'. Aborting the operation.

**ERROR: Failed to deploy application.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Fixed it!

As it states the problem is in Requirements.txt.

Instead of>> pip freeze > requirement.txt

Just added limited resources in the requirements file without version.

fix:requirement.txt contains

flask
flask_sqlalchemy
firebase_admin
pymysql